# Removing a M2M entry with an intermediary model

Tags: django, django-models

I have created the following M2M table with an intermediary model --

```
class Position(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, through ='Timestamp', blank=True, null=True)

class Timestamp(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

I have created the following entries so far --

```
>>> entry1 = Timestamp(userprofile=userprofile, position=position1)
>>> entry2 = Timestamp(userprofile=userprofile, position=position2)
```

Now I have two entries in the `userprofile_timestamp` table

```
-- profile & position1
-- profile & position2
```

How would I delete the `profile & position1` entry? In the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) it mentions using `profile.positions.clear()` to clear ALL the entries, but how would I remove a single entry? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> profile.positions.through.objects.get(position=position1).delete()
```